# WooCommerce: hook for save product details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add some values of attributes to the product before it will be saved (add/edit).

Is there some hooks for this issue?

Comment: Kindly, [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) … Please complete your question with some details about that products values and attributes and some code you are using.

Comment: Try this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63478/save-post-for-custom-post-type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258623/woocommerce-product-filter-range-of-sizes-to-each-subcategory?noredirect=1#comment62044432_37258623